# Found Bundled Python

Tags: python, error

if anyone could help i would be grateful. So I installed blender and when I start it, it shows in cmd "Bundled Python" . I don't know what to do. But its only for .app , when I install blender through zip it works so I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the actual problem that you are having is?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Why don't you use the zipped version, if it works? Also, it would be nice to know what OS you are using. Little details, you know... they sometimes make all the difference.

Comment: You said "it works" so there's no further defination or clarification needed, the .app may be assigned to do that, just ignore it and run the actual Blender that has a three arms like logo(the .exe file).